# get Mobile number in Android Facebook Integration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Facebook integration we can get email adddress by

```
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    User fbUser = new User();
                    Log.v(TAG, user.getProperty("email") + "");
     }
});
```

When some one logged-in with facebook by using MOBILE NUMBER instead of EMAIL id.then,how to get that mobile number instead of email id.?

Comment: On a side note `executeMeRequestAsync` is deprecated! For the original Question - it is not possible check [this](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2011/jan/18/facebook-privacy-data)!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has retracted these features of the API due to privacy concerns.

Source: [Here](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/jan/18/facebook-privacy-data)